# hdparm -m16 (Multi Sector) how do you use this option?

Tags: hard-disk

```
Use of -m is VERY DANGEROUS.
Only the old IDE drivers work correctly with -m with kernels up to at least 2.6.29.
libata drives may fail and get hung if you set this flag.
Please supply the --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing flag if you really want this.
Program aborted.
```

> hdparm -I /dev/sda
>   `R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 8`
>   states that my drive supports multi sector

What is the: --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing flag
Why is this operation so dangerous?
Can it be used with SATA - man pages refers to IDE.

Answer (score 1):

### Foreword

Multi-sector more only affected drives operating in PIO modes.

> Only the old IDE drivers work correctly with -m with kernels up to at least 2.6.29.
> libata drives may fail and get hung if you set this flag.

- Do you have an IDE drive?
- Do you use an **ancient** kernel?
- Do you *really* know what you're doing?

If you answered "yes" three times, then you can go ahead, but then again, you shouldn't have needed to ask this question at all ;-)

### Explanation

Kernel developer Alan Cox about multi-sector mode in DMA modes:

> In DMA modes the 32bit I/O feature and multi-sector mode are not used.

[Source](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-list/2007-April/msg01169.html)

The thing is that most drives in use today will be set by the kernel to use DMA mode by default...